# How to display Month Names from month numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Now i am in a condition, Where I am just displaying the month names and some data grouped by month number. There is a small issue. I need to get month names instead of month numbers from Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(11, 'MM'), 'MONTH') FROM DUAL;
```

**result:**

```
NOVEMBER
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/3896)

Comment: I would think that this would work, but apparently it does. +1

Comment: can we use 'EXTRACT' for display Month Names from month numbers.

Comment: @Taoqir: you want to display month name from month number or from a date value?

Comment: @GolezTrol: when i use to_char(). it dispalys the name of every month,if a month exists more than 1 time in a siatuation then it also apeaers.so i want only 1 acreance of every month.i think in extract it shows the number of month only.so how can we get their names.

Comment: @Taoqir First of all, I'm just commenting here. But above that, I think you should post some actual query and try to make less typing errors. Show a little effort yourself if you want people to help you.

Comment: @Taoqir: Please post your query with sample data

Answer (score 3):

This can be resolve your problem

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(1, 'MM'), 'MON') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Month') FROM DUAL;
```